# Is there an all-in-one control center software that can be used to manage build and test execution and to visualize test results?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, monitoring, testing

If there are no constraints with regards to other components used in the system at all, do you know a software that can be used as a sort of "cockpit" / control center to visualize test result data and to trigger build and test jobs?

I am looking for something like a mix of the Jenkins dashboard (manage and possibly trigger builds and tests) and a Tableau dashboard (rich visualization capabilities) but cannot seem to find something that works out of the box like that - maybe I am just searching in a wrong way though so any hint would be helpful.

**Some context:**

In my department, one team is designing and developing lab hardware and another team is developing the corresponding firmware and drivers. For each release cycle we develop different components of our software on different branches and usually every branch is compiled at least once every night which results in a new version of our driver package per branch. Every driver package is then tested on real hardware using custom test software - for these tests we are maintaining a test farm consisting of about 50 computers, each with an individual hardware setup for specific tests. During test execution, information about individual test results is written to a database and logfiles are stored on a file server. When everything is done, compilation and test results are presented to the developers via a web-based dashboard with a PHP codebase. This whole system was developed some years ago by the team and is maintained and extended to this day.

As time has passed, this old test system has become more and more cumbersome to maintain due to requirements changing and needs growing every release cycle. Thus, recently we have started to look for alternatives to this system that are (hopefully) less work and easier to extend in the future. At the moment we are exploring whether a system consisting of the [Jira plugin Xray](https://www.getxray.app/) for test planning and Jenkins for CI builds and running tests may work for us - but no final decisions have been made yet.